# Non fluorescent DNA stain to visualize Drosophila polytene chromosomes

Tags: genetics, dna, staining

I am working on designing a lab for an undergrad genetics course which involves dissecting and visualising polytene chromosomes from Drosophila salivary glands. I need a non-fluorescent non-antibased staining for the DNA to visualize the chromosomes, as we won't have access to antibodies or an episcope (only compound microscopes). Does anyone know of a DNA dye that could work?

Answer (score 3):

[Giemsa stain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giemsa_stain) should work. It is traditionally used in karyotyping staining. It results in [G-banding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G_banding).